# Training a dataset with just one variable

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, dataset

I have been suggested to train my model with a single labeled internet traffic and then test it with both traffic type I.e., Nirmal and Ddos traffic.

Is it possible to train the model with just one type of data. Data is labelled as Ddos and Normal already..

Comment: What is Nirmal? What kind of model? What is your final goal?

Comment: I misspelled Normal.

Comment: It's a machine learning model where it detect a ddos attack. I was told to only train it with ddos  traffic but when testing it train it with both ddos+normal traffic.